# Content in ScrollView make onClick not working in Android

Tags: android, onclick, scrollview

Now my xml is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/home_page"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:background="@drawable/bg_page"
  android:clickable="true" >
  <ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:clickable="true" ></ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I bind a onClick listener on the main layout (which I need)

```
   RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.home_page);
   layout.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    });
```

When I click on the ScrollView, everything seems ok and a toast will appear. But if I start to add content (here a LinearLayout) to the ScrollView, the toast will not appear on clicking.

```
    <ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/shadow_topbar"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:clickable="true" >

      <LinearLayout
        android:clickable="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" ></LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: try to remove the android:clickable="true" of the linearlayout and update me

Comment: I didn't use it originally, and same here.

Comment: Yes, no toast with or without the clickable attributes.

Comment: give your scrollview an id and check that id by using getId method and compare it to R.id.yourId in onClick method

Comment: @android_Muncher Actually click on the scrollview part doesn't even trigger the onClick listener, so v.getId() thing will not get reached.

Comment: @mrmoment give the linear and relative layout an onclick.

Comment: to what are you setting `onClick`? LinearLayout?

Comment: @Aniruddha First, I tried RelativeLayout (the root, which is also I want). Later I also tried ScrollView and LinearLayout. But none has response to clicks.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a conditional statement to check for the scrollview :

```
  RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.home_page);
  layout.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (v.getId() == R.id.shadow_topbar)
        {
          Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

  });
```

Comment: onClick is not triggered actually, otherwise with or without the "if" condition, a toast will appear.